# Update line in file if already exist

Tags: python, file, text, line

I am writing a simple file with stats on IP address.

I use this code :

```
line = str('%s %12g %12g %12g' %(IP, STAT1, STAT2, THSD))

with open(ficresul, 'a+') as fico:
   if not any(value == x.rstrip('\r\n') for x in fico):
           fico.write(value + '\n' )
           fico.close()
```

and output is something like this:

```
192.168.0.10      15.8121     15.4317          18
192.168.0.20       18.625     12.5085          18
192.168.0.24      20.8323      23.252          18
192.168.0.17      17.6208     15.9218          18
```

It work perfectly for a new IP address. But I would like to update the stats if the ip address is already in the file and not write it in a new line.

How can it be done?

Comment: Just FYI you do not need to enclose your string with `str(...)` - it's already a string!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to read the entire file, update it in memory, then write the whole thing back out (if it has changes).  Trying to update lines in-place will only work if you don't change the length of any lines, and is probably more error-prone.

When storing the contents in memory, use an `OrderedDict` to store them by the key you want to do lookups by.  `OrderedDict` will help avoid spurious changes to the ordering of the lines, which might be nice to have.  Otherwise you can use a regular `dict`.